# Combine pages set of large A4 document into A3 signatures suitable for binding

Tags: pdf, binding

As a way of combining two hobbies I'd like to print and bind a detailed star chart based on the [TriAtlas](https://allans-stuff.com/triatlas/) C series of PDFs.  The end result I want might be like this:

[image: TriAtlas Bound]

My challenge is that combined page count is over 571 pages.  I need a tool to help me combine, scale and re-arrange the pages into signatures for bookbinding.  Sadly a booklet mode printing wouldn't work - I'll be working with signatures of no more than say 7 sheets at a time.

I assume I will need to be able to control the inner edge margins to allow the whole chart to be visible after binding.  I also assume that I would need control of the scale of the pages to provide a clean fit like the sample image above.

Can you recommend a tool that is able to handle the size of files and with the right level of control to be able to stitch these together?  Ideally, I'd prefer something that can run on a MacOS platform, but I can cope with almost any platform really.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with TeX? Because you've not shown any code or even told us which format you're using. In LaTeX, you can just use `pdfpages`.

Comment: See also [`pdfjam`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfjam), a shell script interface to [`pdfpages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). It is part of TeX Live and therefore also available in MacTeX.

Comment: Unrelated to TeX, but if you have experience with phyton, you could also go towards that option, it has some nice support packages to work with pdfs. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660847/how-to-stitch-two-pdf-pages-into-one-in-python

Comment: @cfr I have to admit I just assumed that there would be something in the broader TeX ecosystem that might do the job properly.  Apologies if I've offended you.

Comment: I'm not offended. Just, unfortunately, I had to send my crystal ball in for service this week.

Comment: cabohah & Jes Thanks.  Both of these look like they might suit the task.